# Images not being served with Django/Nginx

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I can't seem to figure out why my images aren't being served when my other static files are.

I'm following along with this [tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/10/14/how-to-deploy-to-digital-ocean.html), and everything is working except for the images aren't being served. All other static files (css, js, etc.) are served however.

I've tried looking at the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/), several SO posts, and the Nginx Docs.

After reading the above, I have tried moving the static files to different places and including STATICFILES_DIR. It looks like the static files are getting found and served by Nginx (except for the img dir). I can see the css and js files when I check Sources with Chrome Developer Tools, just not the img dir and files.

I really appreciate any help you all may have!

**Settings.py**

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
SETTINGS_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
#     os.path.join(SETTINGS_PATH, 'templates'),
# )


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '**'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['138.197.19.209']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'material',
    'material.frontend',
    'material.admin',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'ihc',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ihc_data.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ihc_data.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../static/')
```

**Nginx Sites-Available**

```
upstream app_server {
    server unix:/home/urban/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    # add here the ip address of your server
    # or a domain pointing to that ip (like example.com or www.example.com)
    server_name 138.197.19.209;

    keepalive_timeout 5;
    client_max_body_size 4G;

    access_log /home/urban/logs/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /home/urban/logs/nginx-error.log;

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/urban/static/;
    }

    # checks for static file, if not found proxy to app
    location / {
        try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
    }

    location @proxy_to_app {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }
}
```

**Nginx Error Log (sample)**

```
2016/12/10 17:41:52 [error] 12773#12773: *52 open() "/home/urban/static/img/projects.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 24.11.95.201, server: 138.197.19.209, request: "GET /static/img/projects.png HTTP/1.1", host: "138.197.19.209", referrer: "http://138.197.19.209/vizes/Projects"
2016/12/10 17:41:55 [error] 12773#12773: *54 open() "/home/urban/static/img/savings.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 24.11.95.201, server: 138.197.19.209, request: "GET /static/img/savings.png HTTP/1.1", host: "138.197.19.209", referrer: "http://138.197.19.209/vizes/Projects"
2016/12/10 17:41:55 [error] 12773#12773: *52 open() "/home/urban/static/img/projects.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 24.11.95.201, server: 138.197.19.209, request: "GET /static/img/projects.png HTTP/1.1", host: "138.197.19.209", referrer: "http://138.197.19.209/vizes/Projects"
2016/12/10 17:41:55 [error] 12773#12773: *55 open() "/home/urban/static/img/project_savings.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 24.11.95.201, server: 138.197.19.209, request: "GET /static/img/project_savings.png HTTP/1.1", host: "138.197.19.209", referrer: "http://138.197.19.209/vizes/Projects"
```

**Chrome Developer Tools Console (just in case)**

```
loadScript @ tableau-2.js:28(anonymous function) @ tableau-2.js:32(anonymous function) @ tableau-2.js:33
Projects:94 GET http://138.197.19.209/static/img/projects.png 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general checklist I use is this:

1. Make sure the files exist in the directory:

   ```
   ls -lah /home/urban/static/img/projects.png
   ```
2. Make sure that the files in that directory are readable by the nginx user:

   ```
   # Note we are making these files world-readable here 
   # alternatives are to use a common gunicorn/nginx user
   # or to use a group for both the nginx & gunicorn users.
   chmod 0755 /home/urban
   find /home/urban/static -type d -exec chmod a+rx {} \; 
   find /home/urban/static -type f -exec chmod a+r {} \;
   ```
3. If the files do not exist in (1), make sure you have run the `collectstatic` management command.  It will copy all of the `static` subdirectories from your `INSTALLED_APPS` and copy them over to `STATIC_ROOT`

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! I guess not all the files in the directory were readable by nginx.